# Matlab: adding cell to cell array

Tags: matlab, cell-array

Suppose I have a 3x1 cell array:

```
c = {[1, 2, 3]; [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; [1, 2]}
```

I now want to add another array, to make it a 4x1 array. How do I do this? I have tried the following:

```
c = {c; [1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

But it then tells me that:

```
c = {3x1 cell}    [1x3 double]
```

Whereas I want:

```
c = {4x1 cell}
```

What should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
c=[c; [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

or

```
c{end+1}= [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks. In the first of your examples, why is the syntax to use a square bracket rather than a curly bracket for the outer bracket? I thought the square bracket would be just for adding an element to a regular array.

Comment: `[x,y]` is the syntax to concatenate. [1,2,3,4] concatenates four doubles to a vector. [{1},{1},{1},{1}] concatenates four cells to one cell. If mixed, it's implicit a cell: [{1},{1},1,1].

Comment: To complete the lesson: `c(end+1)= {[1, 2, 3, 4]};`. No better, but hopefully helps demonstrate MATLAB syntax a bit.